# JS from a JS Fiddle not working in browser test

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to implement this cool little [Expand/Collapse js function](http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/eK8X5/7/) I discovered on JS Fiddle, but can't get it to work in a browser test. Could anyone offer a suggestion on what needs to be corrected?

Probably should know this, but as I'm new to Javascript I am stuck. Thanks for your time.

*Here's all the code as I've currently set it up:*

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/teststyle.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="expandcollapse.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
            <li>This is just some random content.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.container {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
    width:100%;
}
.container .header {
    background-color:#d3d3d3;
    padding: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container .content {
    display: none;
    padding : 5px;
}
```

**JS**

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document.ready()());
    $(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Your fiddle is working just fine here, what's exactly your problem?

Comment: What is `$(document.ready()());`?  That should be `$(function(){ // your code... });`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your js call to $(document).ready. Change your code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".header").click(function () {
        $header = $(this);
        //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();
        //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
            //execute this after slideToggle is done
            //change text of header based on visibility of content div
            $header.text(function () {
                //change text based on condition
                return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
            });
        }); rantFormViewModel.wireEvents();
    });
});
```

and everything will work like you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've created your "document.ready" function is not correct.

You can use the correct way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // here goes your code
});
```

Or much simples (like my example below):

```
$(function() {
    // here goes your code
});
```

Try to change your Javascript file to this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".header").click(function () {
        $header = $(this);

        //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();

        //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
            //execute this after slideToggle is done
            //change text of header based on visibility of content div
            $header.text(function () {
                //change text based on condition
                return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document ready wan't called/nested correctly. Try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".header").click(function () {

    $header = $(this);
    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        //execute this after slideToggle is done
        //change text of header based on visibility of content div
        $header.text(function () {
            //change text based on condition
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
        });
    });

  });
});
```